# What integrals in 2D plane and 3D space represent?

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus

We know that if a real valued  function  $f$ is continuous over an interval $[a,b]$ then the following integral $$\int_a^bf(x)dx$$ represents the area between  horizontally the line $y=0$ and the curve of $f$, vertically between the lines $x=a$ and $x=b$. So what represent the following $$\int_{[a,b]\times [c,d]}g(x,y)dxdy$$ and $$\int_{[a,b]\times [c,d]\times [e,f]}h(x,y,z)dxdydz$$ where $g$ and $h$ are two continuous real valued 2d and 3d functions. 
Thanks

Comment: If $h$ represents the density of an object, then $\iiint h dV$ represents the weight of the object. Similar interpretations can be applied for the single and double integrals.

Answer (score 1):

The double integral, represents the sum of the infinite areas under the curves $g(x,y)$ with $x=constant$ defined as:
$$A(y)=\int{g(x,y)\,dx}$$
each one between $y$ and $y+dy$, which gives you a volume. (see [Fubini](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) 's explanation)

The last integral gives you the infinite sum of volumes $V(z)$ defined as 
$$V(z)=\int\int{h(x,y,z)\,dxdy}$$
which gives you a hypervolume.

Imagine that if the function $h$ is a sphere the number $\int V(z) \,dz$ will be the sum of all the volumes of the infinite spheres of radius $z$ between the integration interval $[z_1,z_2]$

Comment: Give me a link to that Fubini's explanation please

Comment: You  have now the link.

Answer (score 1):

karimath, I may contribute.

---

1D integral can be used to calculate area. For example, if we want to calculate an area bounded by $y=f(x)$ and $y=0$ in $x \in [a, b]$, then we can do approximate this by :

$$  A \approx \sum_{i=0}^{N} |f(x_{i})-0| \triangle x, \:\:\: \triangle x = \frac{b-a}{N} $$

$N$ is the number of rectangles, $\triangle x$ being the width of each rectangle $i$, and $f(x_{i})$ is the height of the rectangle $i$.

If we take as many rectangles, we get 
$$  A = \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=0}^{N} |f(x_{i})-0| \triangle x, \:\:\: \triangle x = \frac{b-a}{N} $$ which is defined another way by
$$ A = \int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx$$

---

2D integral is similar. You can approximate the Volume bounded by surface $z=f(x,y)$ and $z=0$, in the region $R : a < x < b, \:\: c < y<d$, by :

$$  V \approx \sum_{j=0}^{N} \sum_{i=0}^{M} |f(x_{i},y_{j})-0| \triangle x \triangle y, \:\:\: \triangle x = \frac{b-a}{M}, \: \: \: \triangle y = \frac{d-c}{N} $$
Notice that $$ |f(x_{i}, y_{j})| \triangle x \triangle y$$
is the volume of the small cuboid with center at position $(x_{i}, y_{j})$, $\triangle x \triangle y$ being the area of the small square as the floor of the cuboid.

Taking as many very-small-cuboids as possible, we get the Volume

$$  V = \int_{c}^{d} \int_{a}^{b} f(x,y) dx dy $$

---

For 3D, it is a bit different. The function $h(x,y,z)$ is a quantity that may be measured. The $\triangle x \triangle y \triangle z$ is the small-volume in which a value $h(x_{i},y_{j},z_{k})$ holds. Connect this to @TrevorNorton comment.

Answer (score 0):

Two-variable integrations refer to the volume enclosed by the surface, the $xy$-plane and the planes perpendicular to $xy$-plane passing through $x=a$ to $x=b$, and $y=c$ to $y=d$, in the case of:

$$\int_{y=c}^{y=d}\int_{x=a}^{x=b}{g(x,y)dxdy}$$

Going by analogy, the three-variable integrations refer to the **hypervolume**, or the 4D analog of our usual 3D volume. This is difficult to visualize for human beings as we are only capable of interacting and understanding a 4D world. However, as the volume in the previous case is considered to be enclosed by plane surfaces, the hypervolume may be described as being enclosed by 3D surfaces.

We may consider

$$\int_{z=e}^{z=f}\int_{y=c}^{y=d}\int_{x=a}^{x=b}{h(x,y,z)dxdydz}$$

as the hypervolume enclosed between:

1. The $xyz$-space at $w=0$
2. The 4D curve $w=h(x,y,z)$
3. The $yzw$-spaces at $x=a$ and $x=b$
4. The $xzw$-spaces at $y=c$ and $y=d$
5. The $xyw$-spaces at $z=e$ and $z=f$